# Accessing R output from Microsoft Azure Platform

Tags: r, azure, cloud

I was doing a simulation study in RStudio using `doAzureParallel` package. It uses a Virtual Machines to do the work and merges the result finally in my RStudio workspace. However, suddenly my RStudio Stopped working. But when I log in to Microsoft Azure Portal I can still see that the jobs are running and it shows the number of simulations running, completed, etc. Once I restart my Rstudio is there any possibility to get the `R` output from the Azure portal? I am new to Azure. I hope I would be helped by some experienced people.

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** You can only monitor the jobs using Azure Portal.

Once the Job Submission object is passed through the Submit call in the SDK and the workload is submitted to the service that has been created using the portal. Now the job can be monitored via the portal or via the client by getting the details of the job using the Job Id that was returned at submission.

This [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/data-guide/technology-choices/r-developers-guide) covers the following Azure services that support the R language:

[image]

The doAzureParallel package is a parallel backend for the widely popular foreach package. With doAzureParallel, each iteration of the foreach loop runs in parallel on an Azure Virtual Machine (VM), allowing users to scale up their R jobs to tens or hundreds of machines.

This [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/tutorial-r-doazureparallel) shows you how to deploy a Batch pool and run a parallel R job in Azure Batch directly within RStudio.